# How can I check a function is a mocked function?

Tags: jestjs, jasmine

We can use [jest.isMockFunction(fn)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestismockfunctionfn) to verify whether a function is mocked or not. From the [source code](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/3cd04a50d82be392879202e5aefd16e1198ab12f/packages/jest-mock/src/index.ts#L916), we know `jestjs` will set a private property `_isMockFunction: true` on the function to be mocked.

Is there any way to do the same thing using the `jasmine` test framework?